# Stop overwriting row in .csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, overwrite

I have been working on a script, created a loop that takes `gene_names` as inputs, and the script runs analyses and stuff from data related to `gene_name`.

Currently I'm trying to export data obtained from said analyses to a .csv file, and I'm using pandas. It's doing what it should, except that I get my data in the row overwritten by the last `gene_name` that the script runs, e.g. `gene_name1` is run and saved, but `gene_name100` is run and is saved on the same row, overwriting it.

Values that I want saved are the `gene_name`(from somewhere up in the script), `average_slope`, `t` and `p-val`.

```
average_slope = np.array(correlation_per_donor.values()).mean()
                    t, p_val = ttest_1samp(correlation_per_donor.values(), 0)
                    print "Averaged slope across donors = %g (t=%g, p=%g)"%(average_slope, t, p_val)
                    print "Saving the slope, t- and p- values"
                    GeneName = [gene_name]
                    Slope = [average_slope]
                    t_value = [t]
                    p_value = [p_val]
                    alleninfDataSet = zip(GeneName,Slope,t_value,p_value)
                    dfalleninfDataSetprev = pd.DataFrame(data = alleninfDataSet, columns=['GeneName','Slope','t_value','p_value'])
                    dfalleninfDataSet = dfalleninfDataSetprev.append([dfalleninfDataSetprev])
                    dfalleninfDataSet.to_csv('Storage00.csv',index=True,header=True)
```

Would be grateful if someone has the solution to resolve this, i know it's simple but googling doesn't help much. Thanks!

Comment: try adding some logic to detect when you're appending and add param `mode='a'` : `dfalleninfDataSet.to_csv('Storage00.csv',index=True,header=True, mode='a')`

Comment: As above, but I would say make header=False. The alternative is to use HDF5Store, which is faster than using csv.

Comment: Do i add in that `mode='a' :` bit as well? Thanks so much guys!